# How to convert character in dataframe to numeric without the loss of decimal

Tags: r, dataframe, double, numeric, tibble

Assume a database in the below format

```
Voltage Global_intensity Sub_metering_1
 <chr>   <chr>            <chr>         
1 234.840 18.400           0.000         
2 233.630 23.000           0.000         
3 233.290 23.000           0.000         
4 233.740 23.000           0.000         
5 235.680 15.800           0.000         
6 235.020 15.000           0.000         
7 235.090 15.800           0.000         
8 235.220 15.800           0.000         
9 233.990 15.800           0.000         
10 233.860 15.800           0.000         
# ... with 2,075,249 more rows
```

I want to convert this character variables of column types to numeric without loss of decimal digits

```
df1$Voltage <-as.double(df1$Voltage,options(digits = 8))
```

```
 Voltage Global_intensity Sub_metering_1
     <dbl> <chr>            <chr>         
 1    235. 18.400           0.000         
 2    234. 23.000           0.000         
 3    233. 23.000           0.000         
 4    234. 23.000           0.000         
 5    236. 15.800           0.000         
 6    235. 15.000           0.000         
 7    235. 15.800           0.000         
 8    235. 15.800           0.000         
 9    234. 15.800           0.000         
10    234. 15.800           0.000         
# ... with 2,075,249 more rows
```

Now I get a result like this with loss of decimal digits. How to rectify it?

Comment: Have you tried with `as.numeric` instead of `as.double`?

Comment: Check `df1$Voltage`, it's tibble not R

Comment: Yea, but it shows the same result of what I got with ```as.double```

Comment: @PoGibas I don't get your point, How do you suggest to change then?

Comment: Use `View(df1)` to inspect your data better.

Comment: ```df1[5,5]```

Result:   236.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is to distinguish between what is shown and what is stored.  `Voltage` is still stored at full precision.

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.numeric)
DF$Voltage
## [1] 234.84 233.63 233.29 233.74 235.68 235.02 235.09 235.22 233.99 233.86
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Voltage Global_intensity Sub_metering_1
1 234.840 18.400           0.000         
2 233.630 23.000           0.000         
3 233.290 23.000           0.000         
4 233.740 23.000           0.000         
5 235.680 15.800           0.000         
6 235.020 15.000           0.000         
7 235.090 15.800           0.000         
8 235.220 15.800           0.000         
9 233.990 15.800           0.000         
10 233.860 15.800           0.000"

library(tibble)
DF <- as_tibble(read.table(text = Lines, colClasses = "character"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @G. Grothendieck